# Confusing inaccuracy in Emgu CV stereo calibration

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

I have 9 stereo camera rigs that are essentially identical.  I am calibrating them all with the same methodology:

1. Capture 25 images of an 8x11 chessboard (the same one for all rigs) in varying positions and orientations
2. Detect the corners for all images using FindChessboardCorners and refine them using CornerSubPix
3. Calibrate each camera intrinsics individually using CalibrateCamera
4. Calibrate the extrinsics using StereoCalibrate passing the CameraMatrix and DistortionCoeffs from #3 and using the FixIntrinsics flag
5. Compute the rectification transformations using StereoRectify

Then, with a projector using structured light, I place a sphere (the same one for all rigs) of known radius (16 mm) in front of the rigs and measure the sphere using:

1. Use image processing to match a large number of features between the two cameras in the distorted images
2. Use UndistortPoints to get their undistorted image locations
3. Use TriangulatePoints to get the points in homogeneous coordinates
4. Use ConvertFromHomogeneous to get the points in world coordinates

On two of the rigs, the sphere measurement comes out highly accurate (RMSE 0.034 mm).  However, on the other seven rigs, the measurement comes out with an unacceptable RMSE 0.15 mm (5x).  Also, the inaccuracy of each of the measurements seems to be skewed vertically.  Its as if the sphere is measured "spherical" in the horizontal direction, but slightly skewed vertically with a peak pointing slightly downward.

I have picked my methodology apart for a few weeks and tried almost every variation I can think of.  However, after recalibrating the devices multiple times and recapturing sphere measurements multiple times, the same two devices remain spot-on and the other seven devices keep giving the exact same error.  Nothing about the calibration results of the 7 incorrect rigs stands out as "erroneous" in comparison to the results of the 2 good rigs other than the sphere measurement.  Also, I cannot find anything about the rigs that are significantly different hardware-wise.

I am pulling my hair out at this point and am turning to this fine community to see if anyone notices anything I'm missing in my above described calibration procedure.  I've tried every variation I can think of in each step of the above process.  However, the process seems valid since it works for 2 of the 9 devices.

Thank you!